# Python code randomly stops, why? (This is for a quiz game)

Tags: python

The following code randomly stops where mentioned in the code.

```
def playSaved(choiceSaved):

    y =  open(choiceSaved,'r')

    for line in y.readlines():
        qna = line.split(" : ")
        randQues.append(qna[0])
        randAns.append(qna[1])

    print("Processing game.....")
    time.sleep(2)
    savedChoice = input("\nOk! Are you ready to play? (Y/N) ")

    # the code stops here, after getting the input

    if savedChoice.lower() == 'y':
        for num in range(len(y.readlines())):
            count = 1
            if "?" in randQues[num]:
                ansForSaved = input(f"Question {count}:\n{randQues[num]}\n> ")
            else:
                ansForSaved = input(f"Question {count}:\n{randQues[num]}\n> ")

            if ansForSaved == randAns[num]:
                print("Correct!")
            else:
                print("Wrong!")
```

I tried looking online, but didn't find anything. I figured i could ask here

it reads the line from a text file and the first part is a question the second part is the answer i want to check if the answer input by user matches the answer based on the txt file

some sample data:

name : jd

country : finland

age : 23

colour:  red

Comment: Are you calling this function from somewhere?

Comment: yes, should i have posted the entire code here?

Comment: There is a chance that the function is being called incorrectly. Please post the code portion where you are calling this function and don't write any non-code text in the middle to avoid confusions regarding indentation. Also, post some of the file contents for reproducing the error.

Comment: No, instead provide sample contents for the file your code reads, and with which we can reproduce the problem using your code. Just enough code  (and file contents) to reproduce the problem, not more.

Comment: No, not the entire code. Just the minimal code to reproduce the issue. Use the edit link below the question.

Comment: The length of y.readlines() will be zero because the input has been exhausted. Therefore even if the user input is either Y or y then nothing will happen. This is not random behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *for* loop:

```
for num in range(len(y.readlines()))
```

...will never be entered because the file contents have already been consumed.

Change to:

```
for num in range(len(randQues))
```